# Columns in Bootstrap not responsive

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying a simple row/ column display with cards. The problem is that my cards are displayed in one column only whatever the screen size

```
<div *ngFor="let f of files$ | async" class="row m-2">
    <div class="col-xm-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
    <div class="card m-2">
    <div>f.name</div>
</div>
```

Is this because of *ngFor?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You repeat columns not rows...

```
<div class="row m-2">
    <div *ngFor="let f of files$ | async" class="col-xm-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
      <div class="card m-2">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a div with the class row inside your `ngFor` to encapsulate the code you currently have. Remove the class row from you div with `ngFor`.

```html
<div *ngFor="let f of files$ | async">
  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-xm-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
      <div class="card m-2">
        <div>f.name</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this results in single column only

Comment: you need more then one file in your array